# Unchecking a checkbox unchecks another checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, unchecked

I want my #pass_through_card checkbox to be unchecked if my #ranged_pricing checkbox is unchecked as you should not be able to check #pass_through_card without having checked #ranged_pricing. The #pass_through_card checkbox does not have to be checked if #ranged_pricing is checked though, which is why I just put "Do Nothing." What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ranged_pricing"/>
<label for="ranged_pricing">
        Ranged Pricing
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="pass_through_card">
<label for="pass_through_card">
    Pass Through Card Association Dues and Assessments
</label>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#ranged_pricing').prop(':checked')) {
    //Do Nothing
} else {
    $('#pass_through_card').removeAttr('checked');
}
});
```

Comment: Don't you need to attach it an event? like this http://jsfiddle.net/8uJ2B/ ?

Comment: If I read your question correctly you only want a certain checkbox to be unchecked if another is unchecked? So only on initialisation right? In which case I'm wondering, why not handle this on the server side?

Comment: PSL - attaching to an event worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's should be just "checked", not ":checked", when you call `.prop()`.

```
if ($('#ranged_pricing').prop('checked')) {
```

The ":checked" notation is for use in selector syntax. When you include the ":" in the call to `.prop()`, the result will always be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
if($("#ranged_pricing").prop('checked') === true){
//do nothing
} else {
$("#pass_through_card").prop('checked', false);
}
```

You may want to bind a checked event to the ranged_pricing as well, to disable the pass_through_card element when it is not checked.